# Does $scope is automatically injected to controller in Angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Initially I was thinking $scope is automatically injected to controller in Angular JS.But Now I am confused. I wrote a small snippet of code.

index.html

```
 <html ng-app>
  <body ng-controller="Controller">
  <input type="text" ng-model="fname">
  <span ng-bind="fname"></span>
 <body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
angular.module('docsSimpleDirective', [])
.controller('Controller', ['$http', function($scope) {
    $scope.fname = 'Foo Bar';
```

}])

As you can see I am not injecting $scope here to the controller. When the page loads, it does not show 'Foo Bar' on the textfield or span. But when I start writing some value on the text field , It reflects on the span. This means 'fname' declared in scope.But why its not showing on the page load. 
Everything works fine when I inject $scope.

Comment: You are injecting `$http` into the controller, but calling it `$scope`.

Comment: @JimCote: No, I have intentionally passed $http as I need that , its just a small piece of code to show the example

Comment: The list of strings in the array should match the params of the controller function. Otherwise, minification will break your app. Your code does not inject $http into the controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You have a couple different things going on.**

**First**, you need to bind the app in some way to the `DOM`, in this case you named your module `docsSimpleDirective` so you need to add `ng-app="docsSimpleDirective` a the same level or above your controllers

```
<!-- added ng-app="docsSimpleDirective" -->
<div ng-app="docsSimpleDirective" ng-controller="Controller">
  <input type="text" ng-model="fname">
  <span ng-bind="fname"></span>
</div>
```

**Second**, you are using the array annotation for defining dependencies which is good. You will run into problems if you don't do this and you try to uglify your code.  The way you currently have it bound you do not pass `$scope` to the controller you are passing `$http` with the name `$scope`.

```
angular.module('docsSimpleDirective', [])
.controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) { 
          // Not ['$http', function($scope)....
    $scope.fname = 'Foo Bar';
}])
```

If you want to pass `$scope` and `$http` to the controller it would be defined like this.

```
.controller('Controller', ['$scope','$http', function($scope,$http) {
```

In short you could do `.controller('Controller', ['$scope','$http', function(foo,bar) { ...` and `foo` would equal `$scope`and `bar` would equal `$http`.  This is done so that when the code is uglified and uglifiery will not change the literal strings for `$scope` and `$http` so the references will not be broken.

**[Here is a working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Malkus/rLh6x7xs/)**

Comment: Is it necessary to pass $scope before $http? Is this order matters?

Comment: No they could be in any order.

Comment: So $scope must be injected for all cases where we need that?

Comment: in any order. BUT, the parameters in the function should be in the same order as the previous defined strings in the array.

Comment: @user3427540 If you don't use `$scope` then you do not have to pass it in.  In most cases you will need `$scope` because it is what binds data to the `DOM`.